# Displacement of the particle and the distance traveled by the particle over the given interval

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Good Day,

I am struggling to find a concrete method of solving for this problem. I have seen a variety of ways this has been solved, but nothing seems to be matching up. This particular example is wanting the total displacement and distance traveled via the use of derivatives.

Question:
A particle moves along a horizontal line. Its position function is s(t) for t ≥ 0. For this problem, find the
displacement of the particle and the distance traveled by the particle over the given interval.
$s(t) = −t^2 + 6t + 27; 0 ≤ t ≤ 4$

Now after taking the velocity function v(t) from the position function s(t) (first derivative) I get $-2t+6$.

Setting this equation to 0 (to find the 0's) I get $-2t+6=0$ => $t=3$

Now I did compute the integral to find the following based off of the velocity function:
$$\int_0^4 -2t+6 \,dx= 8$$ which is the answer to displacement.. I think this is the correct method to find displacement, but of this I am not certain.

At this point I am unsure how to find the total distance traveled. The question was looking for solutions using derivatives, but that path seems even more unclear than using integration. I apologize if this was a bit of a fumble.. I am having a hard time grasping what they are looking for here.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean exactly: If you mean that a point particle is moving along the trajectory $(t, s(t))$ in $\mathbb R^2$ during the time $t\in[0,4]$, then notice that the velocity is $$v(t) = (1, s'(t)) = (1, 6-2t)\in\mathbb R^2$$ and therefore the length of the trajectory of the point particle will be $$\int_0^4 \lvert v(t)\rvert\,\mathrm dt = \int_0^4 \sqrt{1+(6-2t)^2}\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thanks for the reply!
So all that is given for this problem, is that a particle moves along a horizontal line. Its position function is s(t) for t ≥ 0. Find the
displacement of the particle and the distance traveled by the particle over the given interval. Then the equation for s(t) is given along with the interval.
I think the R symbol is something to do with (one-dimensional) scalars, which has not been covered in this course.. so I am not sure if this is related to the problem.

Comment: Ohh so it moves on a horizontal line. In this case you want to compute, if I understand correctly, $$\int_0^4 \lvert s'(t)\rvert\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yes! Correct! My apologies if I neglected that in the initial problem.

Comment: Have fun calculating then . (And note that you computed the integral of $s'$ when you should integrate $\lvert s'\rvert$.) If you need further help, let me know.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Ahhhh! Yes, that's it. You are awesome! Thank you so very much, was spending way to much time struggling over this! I appreciate you!

Answer (score 2):

You did not need to do the whole thing for displacement because it's just
$$\Delta s=s(4)-s(0)=8$$
As for the distance, there is either the way described in the comments i.e.
$$\textrm{Distance}=\int_0^4\left|\dfrac{\textrm ds}{\textrm dt}\right|\,\textrm dt$$
Or as you have already did, $t=3$ is a zero to $v(t)=0$, and that means $v(t)$ will change its sign around it. And so the distance is just
$$\textrm{distance}=|s(3)-s(0)|+|s(4)-s(3)|$$
Although this is basically the same as the integration, but this makes more sense put this way.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)